# Extjs: Delete Row from store-> store.removeAt(RowIndex)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store

I have a bunch of RowIndexes from a store in my GridPanel. I want to delete these from my store.
If I have only one, its no problem, the view from the Grid is refrsehd and the only entry is away.

But when I have more than 0ne, for example 10 RowIndexes and I make this in a loop like here...

```
for(rowIndex in indexes)
 {
    store.removeAt(indexes[rowIndex]);
 }
```

...only a few entries are deleted from the grid. I think the loop is too fast?
I already treid it with a timeout, but doesn't work also.
Is there anyone who has an idea?
THANKS!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try to remove the rows in reverse order. Have you tried that?
Something like

```
var i = indexes.length - 1;
for (; i >= 0; i--){
   store.removeAt(indexes[i]);
}
```

Comment: Really cool! THIS WORKS! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! Doesn't know why it works reverse but it does!

Comment: It's because you change the row index for the following rows when you remove a row. E.g. when removing row with index 5, the row with index 6 is moved to index 5.

Answer (score 4):

I know an answer has already been accepted, but I thought I'd add that calling `Ext.data.Store#removeAt` for each index will fire a `datachanged` event each time the method is called. If you have a `datachanged` listener, you may experience performance issues or unintended behavior. Since `removeAt(index)` is just a convenient alias for `remove(getAt(index))` you can do this instead.

```
function batchRemoveAt(store, indexes) {
    var records = Ext.Array.map(indexes, function (index) {
        return store.getAt(index);
    });
    store.remove(records);
}
```

This will fire a single `datachanged` event for the entire remove, as well as the single `remove` events for each record removed.

Answer (score 0):

try calling `remove` method of `store` which acceps
Model instance or array of instances to remove or an array of indices from which to remove records.

`store.remove([1,2,3]);`

check [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-remove)

Comment: Thanks but the grid view isn't refreshed after this action. Only when I push the REFRESH-BUTTON From the page toolbar, the deleted entries are away. Tried it with Ext.getCmp("ProvGrid").getView().refresh(); But doesn't work

Comment: how the store is referenced? through variable or directly from binded component

Comment: The store is defined in my init function from my controller: var store = Ext.getCmp('ProvGrid').getStore(); ...the refrence works for other functions, so I think this cannot be the problem?!